# C program doesn't run on UNIX but runs on Dev-C++?

Tags: c, unix

I have the following problem:
http://puu.sh/7nEBQ.png

Does anyone know how to fix this? It runs and compiles fine on DevC++ but not on the unix thing

Comment: Post you code please.

Comment: how do you compile the "unix thing"?

Comment: Don't post links to your problem, post your problem. Especially don't post images of text.

Answer (score 2):

You should link the program with `-lm` explicitly.

```
cc evaluate.c -lm
```

See the manual page of the `fmod(3)`.

Comment: Some compilers include `-lm` by default on Unix too. Bit me once.

Comment: @vonbrand, Thank you for comment. BTW, what `bit` mean here?

Comment: Hey, is there a way to fix this without changing the compiling command? E.g. can I change my code? I don't think the TAs marking this will add -lm just for my program?

Comment: @user2976897, TA will add appropriate link option for his/her compiler. I think you don't need to worry about it ;)

Comment: How come it doesn't work when i do #include <math.h> in  my code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a linking error with fmod function.  Try

```
cc evaluate.c -lm
```

to link against the math library.

ps: In the future, please show your code.